# can mod_rewrite be used for this problem?

Tags: php, apache, joomla

We used to have a URL

`http://www.abc.com/index.php?itemID=144`

which is moved to

`http://www.abc.com/index.php?itemID=1556`

we want our users which are hitting the above url(144) to reach to 1556. How can it be achieved. If with mod_rewrite or anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you want to redirect only `144=>1556` or it is just an example. Anyway you can try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=144(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/?$ /$1?id=1556 [NC,R,L]
```

Explanation:

- RewriteCond is making sure there is `id=144` in query string
- RewriteRule is making sure that request URI is `index.php` (optionally followed by a trailing slash).
- If both conditions are satisfied then rule will redirect to `/index.php?id=1556`. (Note use of back reference `$1` instead of repeating `index.php` here).
- Flags used are:

  1. NC - ignore case comparison
  2. R - redirect (by default with status = 302)
  3. L - Mark it as last rule

If you really want to replace multiple old IDs to new IDs then I will suggest you to take a look at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Comment: i just want to redirect url with itemid 144 to 1556

Comment: can u please explain a little more on what you have written in RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Comment: what is [NC,R,L,QSA]

Comment: @sushil: added some explanation but I would humbly suggest: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for better documentation on mod_rewrite.

Comment: Its recognizing the ItemId=144 but doesnot redirect to the new one correctly taking me to http://www.abc.com/xampp/spash.php

Comment: @sushil: There was a mistake in my answer, `QSA` flag wasn't needed and I just took it out. I tested it on my XAMPP and it works fine now. Pls try again.

Comment: @anubhav nearly reached the solution.. but one small help needed.. in your example /$1?id=1556 its taking me to http://localhost/index.php?id=1556 but if the case is http://localhost/appfolder/ then is there some variable i can use..

Comment: Not sure if I completely understood your requirement but if you want to redirect to `localhost/appfolder/?id=1556` then use: `RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/?$ /appfolder/?id=1556 [NC,R,L]`

Comment: ya this way hard coding appfolder works for me what i was asking is if there is a way some regex which can determine the appfolder. However its working very well for me with this hardcoding and thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @anubhava let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1000/discussion-between-sushil-bharwani-and-anubhava)